# Is there any result concerning on the metric dimension of inverse limit?

Tags: gn.general-topology, metric-spaces

To be specific, my question is as follows:

Question: Let $X$ be an inverse limit of compact metric spaces $(X_i, d_i)$, then does it hold

$\dim(X, d) \leq \sup_i \{\dim (X_i, d_i)\}$ for some compatible metric $d$ on $X$?

Comment: What is your notion of inverse limit of metric spaces? Do you mean this one:  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/15948/inverse-limit-in-metric-geometry ?

Comment: Yes, and here metric dimension means the low box dimension.

Comment: Which spaces are inverse limits of finite metric spaces?

Answer (score 1):

I really should avoid answering questions late at night. My original answer is muddled enough to not work. But here is what it should have been:

Let $X_0 = \{0,1\}$ and $X_i = X_{i-1} \times X_0$. Give each $X_i$ the $2-$adic ultrametric. That is the distance between two sequences of $0'$s and $1'$s is $2^{-n}$ where $n$ is the number of share initial symbols the two sequences share. The projections maps are given by truncation. The inverse limit is now $\mathbb{Z}_2$ which has box counting dimension equal to one.

Comment: This construction does not seem to be an inverse limit of metric spaces in Petrunin's sense (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/15948/inverse-limit-in-metric-geometry). 

Comment: Even it fails in the general setting, how about making X_i to be the compact metric (abelian) group?

Comment: @Misha thank you for making me think a bit longer about this. @Bingbing Liang yes, the idea is to do that and then take the limit. Z_2 is just the easiest example of this to write down.

Comment: Good, now it works. 

Comment: In general, the low box dimension is dependent on the choice of metric. @BSteinhurst Is it clear that each compatible metric on $\mathbb{Z}_2$ induces a nonzero low box dimension? 

Comment: @Bingbing Liang, it is not clear to me right now whether the nonzero lower box counting dimension always holds for any compatible sequence of metrics. There are lots of metrics out there and I am not certain enough to rule out a counter example.

Comment: @BSteinhurst, OK, thanks for your concern of my question.